# Why 'in' is faster than `__contains__`?

Tags: python

I thought that `in` is just a manifest of `__contains__`

```
In [1]: li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [2]: 4 in li
Out[2]: True

In [3]: li.__contains__(4)
Out[3]: True
```

However `in` is 2x faster

```
In [4]: %timeit 4 in li
10000000 loops, best of 3: 103 ns per loop

In [5]: %timeit li.__contains__(4)
The slowest run took 10.06 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 213 ns per loop
```

Can you explain the differences between the two and why is `in` faster?

Comment: Probably the same reason why `{}` is faster than `dict()`. The method call overhead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the standard implementation of Python, `in` doesn't quite use `__contains__` directly. `in` actually uses the C-level `sq_contains` function pointer in the struct representing an object's type. For types with a `__contains__` implemented in Python, `sq_contains` points to a function that looks up and invokes the `__contains__` method, but for types with a `__contains__` implemented in C, `sq_contains` points straight to the C implementation of the method.

Since `list.__contains__` is implemented in C, `4 in li` gets to invoke the C implementation directly, without passing through the overhead of a Python method lookup and a Python function call. `li.__contains__(4)` has to perform the Python method lookup and Python function call, so it's substantially slower.

If you want to see the code path involved for `4 in li`, you can follow the call hierarchy down from [`COMPARE_OP`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/ceval.c#l2548) in the bytecode evaluation loop. You'll see that it uses [`cmp_outcome`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/ceval.c#l4781):

```
TARGET(COMPARE_OP)
{
    w = POP();
    v = TOP();
    if (PyInt_CheckExact(w) && PyInt_CheckExact(v)) {
        ...
    }
    else {
      slow_compare:
        x = cmp_outcome(oparg, v, w);
    }
```

[`cmp_outcome`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/ceval.c#l4781) uses [`PySequence_Contains`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/abstract.c#l2397):

```
static PyObject *
cmp_outcome(int op, register PyObject *v, register PyObject *w)
{
    int res = 0;
    switch (op) {
    ...
    case PyCmp_IN:
        res = PySequence_Contains(w, v);
        if (res < 0)
            return NULL;
        break;
```

[`PySequence_Contains`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/abstract.c#l2397) looks up the `sq_contains` field of the `tp_as_sequence` field of the C struct representing the list type:

```
int
PySequence_Contains(PyObject *seq, PyObject *ob)
{
    Py_ssize_t result;
    if (PyType_HasFeature(seq->ob_type, Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_SEQUENCE_IN)) {
        PySequenceMethods *sqm = seq->ob_type->tp_as_sequence;
        if (sqm != NULL && sqm->sq_contains != NULL)
            return (*sqm->sq_contains)(seq, ob);
```

[This field](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/listobject.c#l2526) stores a function pointer to [`list_contains`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/listobject.c#l437), the C function implementing the list containment check. At no point does Python have to perform any dict lookups to find the method, or allocate a method object to represent the method, or build a tuple of arguments to pass to the method.

Comment: Your last paragraph is somewhat confusing, do you mean `list.__contains__` doesn't require dict-lookups, etc? You earlier stated that it does (and `meth = li.__contains__; meth(4)` is faster than `li.__contains(4)`). Also you forgot the code formatting in the middle. But I like your answer, very handy background knowledge especially about the control flow. Much better than just disassembling (in my opinion) the code or my attempt at answering.

Comment: Deep stuff. Thanks for the insight under the hood.

Answer (score 5):

Probably the same reason why `{}` is faster than `dict()`. The method call introduces an extra overhead:

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> c = lambda: 4 in li
>>> d = lambda: li.__contains__(4)
>>> dis(c)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (4)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (li)
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis(d)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (li)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (__contains__)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (4)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

See `CALL_FUNCTION` in the later case.

Comment: This doesn't explain why `in` doesn't have the same method call overhead.

Comment: `in` applies `COMPARE_OP`

Comment: And you'd expect `COMPARE_OP` to call the `__contains__` method of `li`, incurring method call overhead.

Comment: I wouldn't expect `__contains__` to be called as an attribute (via dot reference) when using `in` since it's a language construct

Comment: And it's not, but you should explain how it *is* called. For someone unfamiliar with the CPython internals, it's not clear how else `__contains__` could possibly be invoked.

Comment: How can I know which function is being called at stage 9? Does `__contains__` calls `in`?

Comment: @Aguy `__contains__` does not call `in`. It already implements the logic to check for list membership.

Comment: @user2357112 I would suppose there are alternative hooks for calling such methods. I haven't had much experience with CPython internals. Would be great if you could help improve the answer in that regard

Answer (score 2):

This answer somewhat builds upon the explanation of @MosesKoledoye but without any disassembling of source code.

There are several reasons why the `.__contains__` is slower than just using `in`:

- Each time you access a method/function/class/property by using `.` this introduces a lookup inside the class/instance dictionary. This introduces some overhead.
- For custom classes a call to `in` is translated to `.__contains__` (or `.__iter__`) but this isn't necessarily true for all python builtins. Python lists are implemented in C and so a `something in list` can be translated to a C-function without needing to call `__contains__` or `__iter__`.
- The `in list` is directly forwarded to C code (`COMPARE_OP`) which is much faster than accessing a python function and then calling the C code (`CALL_FUNCTION`).

In general: For python built-ins using literals like `in` may be faster but this is (in general) not true for custom classes. Most of the data model in python applies to custom classes. `list.__contains__` is probably only implemented to fit the data model conventions and not because it is needed or faster.